# python, how to reference a data_frame row to execute in parallel

Tags: python, dataframe, parallel-processing

I have written a simple for loop that iterates per rows of a data frame. Each row of a data frame is compared with all entries of the second data frame (second input of that function).

Now this function after some comparisons and searching returns back rows of a **new** dataframe that has the following structure.

```py
new_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['1','2','3','4','5','6','dist','unique','occurence','timediff','id'], dtype='float')
```

The for loop now looks like this:

```py
for i in range(0,small_pd.shape[0]):
    new_df=new_df.append(SequencesExtractTime(small_pd.loc[i],large_pd.loc[i]) )
```

I am trying to find a way to run this code in parallel since it take years to execute on a single core.

I have found the joblib package

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
print(Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(SequencesExtractTime(small_pd,large_pd)(i) for i in range(0,small_pd.shape[0])))
```

The problem now is how to use the two data frames properly so can be used from the parallel loop. I think the problem is that I do not know how to write the input arguments from the form of I had them in the for loop

```py
small_pd.loc[i]
```

in a form for the Parallel function.

Can you please help me with this problem?
Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Are your DataFrames contain >1m rows? If so, doing crude loops even in parallel will take a toll on memory.

If you really need to compare each column entry from 1st df to the 2nd df. Try to consider list parsing instead.

That way you can take advantage `.intersection()` or `.difference()` whichever suits your need for filtering [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

Or try `groupby()` from pandas

Comment: The input dataframe has around 45k rows. Thanks not too many. The output will be around 5 times larger so 200k rows. I wanted to try the parallel execution and see how far I can get. If needed I can split the initial dataset to 4-10 parts and run each one separately.

Comment: That's still not a huge dataset. Crude loops however will take a few minutes to finish. So I suggest placing the column you want to check from your first file into a list, and placing the column you want to compare it to from your second file into a list as well. Now to get whatever you need to find, you can use `intersection` method to check for intersection and `difference` to get all items in first list that is not in second list. Store it in a new list, use `isin` method in pandas to filter whichever file, with that new list.